# Preview video in Elementary nautilus?

Tags: 11.04, video, nautilus-elementary, previews

Im using Ubuntu 11.04. In Elementary nautilus, I can preview a music thumbnail by hover the mouse cursor on it. But I cant do it with the video files. I've set "Only for the files smaller than : 100MB" in Preferences/Preview but nothing changed. Please help!

Comment: get Gloobus preview

Comment: I got it already. But I want to preview the video by hovering on it too. Is there anyway else?

Comment: There's no such thing like that that i know of, only Gloobus preview plays video previews, the default nautilus preview only plays audio on hoverig not video.

Comment: on Nautilus elementary never as it's not being developed anymore, should probably wait for Nautilus 3 to add that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previewing video like that is not possible on nautilus - at least not yet.

By the way,  for the part with the music thumbnail : it is possible on both standard nautilus and elementary one, not just on nautilus elementary

Answer (score 1):

If you're using nautilus elementary, you can try [gloobus](http://gloobus.net/).

Comment: I got it already. But I want to preview the video by hovering on it too. Is there anyway else?